# Cassandra: efficient way to compare stats?

Tags: database, cassandra

I want to compare stats by hour between today and yesterday. 
My structure looks like that

```
CREATE TABLE stats0( id UUID,hour_0 INT, hour_1 INT,[all hours], hour_23 INT,total BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE stats1( id UUID,hour_0 INT, hour_1 INT,[all hours], hour_23 INT,total BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE today( id UUID, today INT, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

This is the example.

DAY 1:

- today set to 0.
- stats load in table stats0

DAY 2:

- today set to 1.
- stats of today load in stats1 and compare with stats0

DAY 3:

- truncate stats0
- today set to 0.
- stats of today load in stats0 and compare with stats1

DAY 4:

- truncate stats1
- today set to 1.
- stats of today load in stats1 and compare with stats0

And continue like that.
I compare hours of stats0 and stats1 during the day.

Is there a way to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nasubik To avoid renaming the tables every day, which is one inefficiency here, you could create a structure where the date is in the table, like this:

CREATE TABLE stats( id UUID, date, hour_0 INT, hour_1 INT,[all hours], hour_23 INT,total BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

I would test this as well; this turns the table sideways and performance will depend on how you're loading your data into the table:

CREATE TABLE stats( id UUID, date, hour (0-23) INT, the_stat_value INT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

Comment: Oh didn't think that way to do it, I think is better as you say. Thank you!